# SSIS container that can act both as source and target

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to transfer data in a SSIS package, from A to B, and from B to C. What is the best way to do so? I created two flows (`OLE DB Source` to `OLE DB Destination`) inside the same data flow, but when I run the task in the control flow, I guess the two flows are run concurrently and then I get only data to be transferred in one.

There isn't a container that can act both as source and target?

I read about making a loop waiting for the first task to finish, but that should be very ineffective in case I have a lot of data, which is going to happen in my use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make two dataflows, and put one after the other in the control flow.

To answer your central question, a script component can act as both a source and a destination.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Tab Alleman, creating two Data Flow tasks under the Control tab with one before the other in series will resolve the issue.  The first will handle A to B and the second will handle B to C.  With this approach the second Data Flow task will not begin until the first one is complete... no wait loop required.

I'm guessing you are probably new to SSIS development and will find the following material helpful in planning future packages.

[10 SQL Server Integration Services Best Practices](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2013/09/16/top-10-sql-server-integration-services-best-practices/)

[Top 10 Methods to Improve ETL Performance using SSIS](http://www.developer.com/db/top-10-methods-to-improve-etl-performance-using-ssis.html)

[SSIS Naming Conventions](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2016/12/ssis-naming-conventions.html) - This covers both Control and Data Flow tasks.

Hope this helps.